# Lubuntu and Firestarter

Tags: lubuntu, firestarter

I've just switched from Ubuntu to Lubuntu and I have installed Firestarter.

Is this advised? The reason I ask is because a whole load of Gnome related packages were also installed alongside Firestarter. As I understand it, Gnome is not part of Lubuntu. Should I be avoinding anything which requires Gnome-based packages now that I am on Lubuntu? Is there a better firewall to use with Lubuntu

Finally, after a clean install of Lubuntu, I had to go online to get Firestarter. Does this mean that my system was without protection during this period? Could someone have haxored me during this time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most users won't need to use a firewall at all, since Ubuntu doesn't have any open ports by default. But Firestarter is a only a GUI to configure the firewall. It will still run when you're not running Firestarter. It'll just use the same configuration until you change it.

I see nothing bad about installing Gnome packages in Lubuntu, and vice versa. For instance, I've used the panel from LXDE in Gnome. The packages will just be installed. They won't be used until you use something that requires it.